# Cron job schedule

Tags: cron

I want to schedule cron job for my app to do a particular task. How can i schedule in this requirement?

Requirement:
cron-data.js should be run every Mondays to Fridays hourly from 9:30am - 3:30pm.

Comment: https://ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSWSR9_11.4.0/com.ibm.mdmhs.dev.platform.doc/tasks/t_to_use_cron_job_to_sched_bulk_proc_service.html

Answer (score 3):

```
30 09-15 * * 1-5 [Commad to Execute]
```

30 : **30th Min**

09-15 : **9AM to 3 PM**

* :  **Every day**

* : **Every Month**

1-5 : **Mon to Fri**

Answer (score 1):

This is just an example. You can try this and customize as per your requirement.

```
# Use the hash sign to prefix a comment
# +---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  +------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  +---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  +------- month (1 - 12)
# |  |  |  |  +---- day of week (0 - 7) (Sunday=0 or 7)
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Run my cron job every Monday to Friday hourly from 9:30am
30 9 * * 1,2,3,4,5 cron-data.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference - to access the file where jobs are scheduled, run the following command in your console:

`crontab -e`

http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference